# Event listening is clashed when same componet is used twice on single page

Tags: javascript, stenciljs, stencil-component

I am using stencil framework in my project to create components. Project structure is tree base means subcompacts are having sub components as well. I have used custom events at many places.

My concern is when I listen events with parameter `target:body`, code is executed twice as I have used same component twice on single page. I have created sample component to show the issue/concern.

**Main component code snippet**

```
import { Event, EventEmitter, Component, Prop, h } from '@stencil/core';
@Component({
   tag: 'my-component'
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Prop() first: string;
  @Prop() middle: string;
  @Prop() last: string;
  @Event() nameClick: EventEmitter;

handleClickEvent(e): void {
 this.nameClick.emit({ name: `${this.first} ${this.middle} ${this.last}` });
}

render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <div onClick={(e) => this.handleClickEvent(e)}><u>Click here to show you name!!</u></div>
       <p><div>Your full name</div><sub-component></sub-component></p>
     </div>
   )
 }
}
```

**Sub component snippet**

```
import { Component, h, Listen, State } from '@stencil/core';
@Component({
  tag: 'sub-component'
})
export class SubComponent {

@State() fullName: string;

@Listen('nameClick', { target: 'body' })
onNameClick(event: CustomEvent) {
    this.fullName = event.detail.name;
}
render() {
    return <input type="text" value={this.fullName}></input>
 }
}
```

**Html page where component is used**

```
<div id="content" class="tabcontent">
 <div style="width:50%;float:left">
  <p>Component 1</p>
  <my-component first="Stencil" middle="web" last="component"></my-component>
 </div>
 <div style="width:50%;float:right">
  <p>Component 2</p>
  <my-component first="Stencil" middle="web" last="component"></my-component>
 </div>
</div>
```

It seems this code is culprit to listen event twice  `@Listen('nameClick', { target: 'body' })`.

[Gif for demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QSu7.gif)

Thanks in advance for a help!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `target: body` for this kind of thing is a lot like listening for a click on a button from body which will be triggered for every click - it's just not the right way to approach the problem.

Your parent `my-component` already knows which `sub-component` is which because it is part of the template, so it can update directly if you make `fullName` a @Prop.

For example (partial code):

```
export class SubComponent {

  @Prop() fullName: string;

  render() {
    return <input type="text" value={this.fullName}></input>
  }
}

export class MyComponent {
  ...
  private _childComponent: HTMLSubComponentElement;

  handleClickEvent(e): void {
    this._childComponent.fullName = `${this.first} ${this.middle} ${this.last}`;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={(e) => this.handleClickEvent(e)}><u>Click here to show you name!!</u></div>
        <p>
          <div>Your full name</div>
          <sub-component ref={el => this._childComponent = el}></sub-component>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you don't want to use a @Prop - you could also define a @Method to set the `fullName` value.

Comment: Thanks @Tranter for your solution. I will try this solution in my project.

Answer (score 0):

If it is Parent and Child Component, you don't need to attach the target to body.

```
@Listen('nameClick', {})
onNameClick(event: CustomEvent){
   this.fullName = event.detail.name;
}
```